# MySQL - Rows to Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns, `participant_id, question, answer`. for each participant, there will be five question.

How do fetch a report like against each participant each question as a column header and answer as value. So in report for each participant there will be one entry in report?

[image: table structure:]

expected output:
group using participant_id and each question should be the column header and custtusponding answer will be the column value.

Comment: Please add tables schema, sample data and the desired result.

Comment: @McNets Thanks for quick response ,added schema details to the question

Comment: Still not clear, is there any `question_id`, please add you CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @McNets yes question field is the question_id

Comment: "and all the children are above average".

Comment: @ShamseerPc - You have provided "sample data"; you have _not_ provided the "schema", which is best done using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to pivot table , Try This

```
create view pivot_questions as (
  select
    questions.*,
    case when question = "question1" then itemvalue end as question1,
    case when itemname = "question2" then itemvalue end as question2,
    case when itemname = "question3" then itemvalue end as question3,
    case when itemname = "question4" then itemvalue end as question4,
    case when itemname = "question5" then itemvalue end as question5
  from questions
);

select * from pivot_questions;
```

Comment: It returns 5 rows per participant, I just want to return one row per participant with 5 column as question answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add another condition in select query

```
select participant_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(question1 SEPARATOR '') as question1,
GROUP_CONCAT(question2 SEPARATOR '') as question2,
GROUP_CONCAT(question3 SEPARATOR '') as question3,
GROUP_CONCAT(question4 SEPARATOR '') as question4,
GROUP_CONCAT(question5 SEPARATOR '') as question5 
  from pivot_questions
  group by participant_id
```